# Где я ошибся, не могу понять... Не происходит выборка из таблицы в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Прохожу курс "GeekBrains => PHP. Личный блог"
Все пошагово, все проверил, а понять где я сделал баг, - не могу понять, Помогите!

Есть. index.php

```
<?php
require_once("database.php");
require_once("models/articles.php");

$link = db_connect();
$articles = articles_all($link);

include ("views/articles.php");
?>
```

Есть файл подключения...

```
<?php
define('MYSQL_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('MYSQL_USER', 'root');
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '');
define('MYSQL_DB', 'blog');

function db_connect() {
    $link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_SERVER,MYSQL_USER,MYSQL_PASSWORD,MYSQL_DB)
    or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));
    if(!mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf8')) {
        sprintf("Error :".mysqli_error($link));
    }
    return $link;
}
?>
```

Файл articles.php

```
<?php
function articles_all($link) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if (!$result)
        die(mysqli_error($link));

    $n = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $articles = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $articles[] = $row;
    }
    return $articles;
}
```

А вот viewшка

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Блог</title>
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Каскадная страница</h1>
    <?php foreach ($articles as $a): ?>
    <div class="article">
        <h3>
            <a href="article.php?id=<?=$a['id']?>"><?=$a['title']?></a>
        </h3>
        <em>Публикация: <?=$a['date']?></em>
        <p><?=$a['content']?></p>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

И вопрос, вроде бы все работает, ошибок не выдает... Мало того, к примеру если в таблице в базе есть 5 строк, то в странице уже выполненном выдает пять секции со статьями... Но пустые! т.е. подключается хорошо, а вот строки он не выводит. с названиями, датами, текстами...

Comment: https://hkar.ru/T1lO Вот скриншот страницы )

Comment: Перед foreach сделайте var_dump($articles); и посмотрите на структуру данных

Comment: @DaemonHK Вот новый скриншот https://hkar.ru/T1mw

Comment: И? Вы не видите своего косяка?)) используйте mysqli_fetch_assoc вместо mysqli_fetch_row, или используйте числовые индексы из вашего получившегося массива.

Comment: Пойду выпью яду... Спасибо! )